# for( in ) loop index is string instead of integer

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Consider following code:

```
var arr = [111, 222, 333];
for(var i in arr) {
    if(i === 1) {
        // Never executed
    }
}
```

It will fail, because `typeof i === 'string'`.

Is there way around this? I could explicitly convert `i` to integer, but doing so seems to defeat the purpose using simpler `for in` instead of regular `for`-loop.

**Edit:**

I am aware of using `==` in comparison, but that is not an option.

Comment: Compare using `==` so no type check will be included

Comment: Simplicity is not the case here. You should use regular `for` loop for iterating arrays.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you know what kind of data is stored in `i` and why is a String

Comment: [*Simply* don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) Just because a hammer is a simpler tool than an electric screwdriver, you shouldn't use it for screws.

Comment: Ruined 72 hours of my time for this!!!

Comment: I agree with Bergi, but I think Javascript should fix the behavior of for(...in) for arrays since its behavior right now is pathological.

You can use `for(const index of arr.keys()) {}`  as a drop-in replacement in the meantime, as this is friendly for async code (unlike forEach).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have got several options

1. Make conversion to a Number:

   ```
   parseInt(i) === 1
   ~~i === 1
   +i === 1
   ```
2. Don't compare a type (Use `==` instead of `===`):

   ```
   i == 1 // Just don't forget to add a comment there
   ```
3. Change the for loop to (I would do this but it depends on what you are trying to achieve):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (i === 1) { }
   }

   // or

   arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
      if (i === 1) { }
   }
   ```

By the way you should not use `for...in` to iterate through an array. See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
>   integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach
>   or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where
>   the order of access is important.

Comment: I did some reading, and I simply need to just stop using `for in` for arrays. It seems to be too easy to break unexpectedly.

Comment: Exactly, I think that `forEach` is a good replacement. Simple and also faster solution than `for...i`. You should use `for...i` only if you need to iterate trough an object.

Comment: forEach is not good if you're writing async code. The behavior of for...in for arrays is just stupid, it is NEVER what you want it to be. You can use for(const index of arr.keys()) {} as a drop-in replacement, but it seems to me that for...in should actually work properly.

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) instead.

Answer (score 3):

With `===` you compare also the type of values. Use `==` instead:

```
if ( i == 1 ) {}
```

or cast `i` to integer:

```
if ( +i === 1 ) {}
```

Also you can try with 'standard' `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need browser support below IE9, you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If you do, use the good ol' `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {}` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i in arr) { //i is not the value of an element of the array, but its "attribute name"
    if(arr[i] === 1) {

    }
}
```

In any case, I'd use the good old classic `for` syntax, it's the recommended way to deal with arrays

Comment: No, the intent is to compare the index.

Answer (score 0):

for-in loops properties in object, you could use for-of to loop array.

```
for (const i in [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]) {
    console.log(`${typeof i}: ${i}`);
}
string: 0
string: 1
string: 2
string: 3
string: 4
```

---

```
const obj = {
    11: 'a',
    22: 'b',
    33: 'c',
    44: 'd',
    55: 'e',
}
for (const i in obj) {
    console.log(`${typeof i}: ${i} -> ${obj[i]}`);
}
string: 11 -> a
string: 22 -> b
string: 33 -> c
string: 44 -> d
string: 55 -> e
```

---

```
for (const i of [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]) {
    console.log(`${typeof i}: ${i}`);
}
number: 11
number: 22
number: 33
number: 44
number: 55
```